# Does static index of array will change the array?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to break a path name into a sequence using strtok. But I encount a question, my code is showed below:

```
int main(void)
{
    char test[] = "/hoe/wahoo/Documents/hello/test";
    char *str[8]; 
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;

    str[index] = strtok(test, "\\/");
    while (str[index] && *str[index]) {
        index++;
        str[index] = strtok(NULL, "\\/");
    }

    for (index=0; index<8; index++) {
        if (str[index] && *str[index]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, I get a error `segmentation error`, and I know the source of the error. Once, I change the `int index = 0;` to `static index = 0;` in the line 5. I find that it does work!!

So why? It seems like I change the index of array into static, that the array will be static.

Comment: Note that `strtok` modifies the original string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with static variables. You just need to initialise `str[]`, otherwise the unused elements will contain random garbage and you will get undefined behaviour (most likely because you attempt to iterate beyond the end of the array).

Note that undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour - literally *anything* can happen when you do something like this. Random changes to unrelated areas of the code may well affect the observed outcome, but this is really just a distraction and it doesn't address the underlying problem.

So change:

```
char *str[8];
```

to:

```
char *str[8] = { 0 };
```

and all will be well.

Comment: Well, I know I do not initial the point array, but why I change the index of array into static index, I can get the correct reult?

Comment: @Asuka: undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour - literally *anything* can happen when you do something like this. Random changes to unrelated areas of the code may well affect the observed outcome, but this is really just a distraction and it doesn't address the underlying problem.

Comment: Well, I think you are right. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

In your first loop, you carefully check for a non-null ptr:

```
str[index] = strtok(test, "\\/");
while (str[index] && *str[index]) {
    index++;
    str[index] = strtok(NULL, "\\/");
}
```

But in your second loop you don't, and you don't initialize `str` to have values, which introduces undefined behavior. That's why when you change some other variable, such as by changing one to static, different behavior occurs.

```
for (index=0; index<8; index++) {
    if (str[index] && *str[index]) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

This loop would need to be:

```
for (index = 0; str[index] && *str[index]; ++index) {
    ++count;
```

Or better still, you could write the whole as

```
int main(void)
{
    char test[] = "/hoe/wahoo/Documents/hello/test";
    char *str[8] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
    int count = 0;

    str[count] = strtok(test, "\\/");
    while (str[count] && *str[count]) {
        str[++count] = strtok(NULL, "\\/");
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

--- EDIT ---

Also note that `strtok` modifies your original string. When you are done with your loop, the path separtors in `test` will be replaced with '\0's.

Answer (score 0):

You got an excellent answer already.

Here is another piece of code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char test[] = "/hoe/wahoo/Documents/hello/test";
    char delims[] = "\\/";
    char *str[8]; 
    int count = 0;

    str[0] = strtok(test, delims);
    while (str[count]) {
        printf("%s,", str[count]);
        count++;
        str[count] = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }

    printf("\n%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
hoe,wahoo,Documents,hello,test,
5
```

Mind you: that is readable, but it is inefficient, since it uses indexes to address the elements in str.

Here is what I would write instead (pointers give you the edge):

```
int main()
{
    char test[] = "/hoe/wahoo/Documents/hello/test";
    char delims[] = "\\/";
    char *str[8];
    char **p = str;
    int count = 0;

    *p = strtok(test, delims);
    while (*p) {
        printf("%s,", *p);
        count++;
        *(++p) = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }

    printf("\n%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: all the code above does not check the max number of tokens is reached. I'd recommend to add it in to avoid a segfault/unpredictable behaviour.